# Why is this USB-C cable working in only one orientation?

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, usb, usb-c

#### Background

I have a friend who, for the sake of his project, is wanting to lead a USB-C cable out from his USB-C Arduino into a PCB he designed. From there another USB-C port would sit outside of the gaming controller that his PCB is designed for so that anyone using said controller can plug/unplug it from their computer at any time.

[image]

#### Problem

His problem is when his cable is plugged in one orientation, it works fine. However, when he flips the plug it will at most power his Arduino board but his PC will not recognize it. I have tried looking up other people's experiences regarding similar issues with USB-C, but either their issues were slightly different or this is something I'm not quite understanding.

Neither me nor my friend know for sure if the problem is in the orientation of the cord that leads from his PCB to the Arduino, in the cord that leads from the PCB to the PC, or if it is a combination of the two. He has however tried different USB-C cables, and they yielded the same results which tells me the problem is within the PCB design.

Comment: 1/2 of the pins are not connected

Comment: Do you have a datasheet or any other info for thst USB-C connector you're using?

Comment: Two things needed to solve the problem is connector pinout and data sheet. We can't decipher from the picture what wires are between receptacles. Also, this is the reason why receptacles must be on devices, and USB extension adapters with two receptacles is not allowed to exist. Officially that violates USB specification.

Comment: @justme -- You can decipher it just fine. Referencing a standard is sufficient. USB (-C) defines where the pins are located on the connector and their function. It also defines what happens when you add a standardized cable across receptacles. Your claim about USB violations is, likewise, not correct as USB explicitly prefers that USB-C receptacles are mated to other USB-C receptacles (via plug-to-plug cables) -- example: cell phone chargers with USB-C receptacles.

Comment: @DrFriedParts You misunderstood. Any manufacturer can manufacture any kind of connector with any kind of PCB footprint and different connectors are manufactured for different purposes. Sure the pinout of the receptacle is well defined but we can't see how pins are connected. And no, standard specifically forbids existence of this kind of two-receptacle extension plug - so of course devices are allowed to have receptacles. Each cable will also swap some pins so PCB needs pin swaps - but irrelevant because this kind of plugs should not exist. (online shops still sell them and people buy them).

Comment: @justme -- The USB specification defines all the things you think you "can't see." This design is allowed. It's Arduino (R) --> (P) Cable (P) --> (R) PCB (R) --> (P) Cable (P) --> (R) Computer. The actual answer is that the OP needs to implement the USB2-C schematic correctly (there are some signaling parts/shorts missing). There's nothing proprietary in the design exclusive of the USB specification, so no datasheets or additional information is needed to answer the question as submitted.

Comment: @DrFriedParts Only cables and adapters listed in USB Type-C specification are allowed. Please quote where in the specification an adapter or cable with two Type-C receptacles is listed (hint: it is not listed and thus not allowed by specification).

Comment: @Justme Here is the datasheet and pinout. (I took the pinout from a different picture because the datasheet was lacking. 
Datasheet: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2006181823_SHOU-HAN-TYPE-C-16P-073_C668624.pdf
Pinout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBFCV.png

I saw in one reddit post where one guy said to connect DP1 to DP2 and also connect DN1 to DN2. Does that sound correct you think?

Comment: @justme -- I think we both misunderstood (or I misunderstood the OP). You can have a device (my interpretation of the OP's intent to build a PCB) with two USB receptacles (USB Spec r2-2019 p.224, et al.), but (of course) you can't have a cable with two USB receptacles. My conclusion was the OP's schematic was wrong because his PCB didn't implement a valid USB solution (e.g. a hub or active repeater) between the receptacles and your conclusion was a "pass-through" isn't allowed -- you took fault with the connectors and I took fault with the stuff in between, but we're saying the same thing.

Comment: @DrFriedParts I think we mean the same after all. That PCB and connectors is exactly same as cable or adapter that has two receptacles and wires between them - not allowed. Of course you can make a device with as many separate/individual Type-C receptacles as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

USB C is not designed for an USB C receptable to and USB C receptable. Not all wires are connected within the plug, so not all signals gets passed through.

You have 3 options:

- Mechanically move USB C port from the arduino to the case (and connect all the wires manually)
- Use an (techinically non-standard) USB C port to USB C receptacle extension cable that connects all the 24 pins through
- Remove the USB C receptable from the arduion, and make a new daughter port on the outside of the case, manually connect D-, D+, GND, VBUS, CC1, CC2 to it. Note that D- and D+ needs to be connected to both sides of the receptacle